# Invoke-Command is working locally but not through Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

i need to execute a bat/exe on remote Server which is not a Jenkins Slave. for which i am using windows powershell add-in as build in Jenkins.

below Invoke-Command  is executing the bat file on server when executing the shell from local machine, but same is not working when running it through Jenkins Job

```
$user=$args[0]
$pass = $args[1]
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PsCredential -argumentlist $user, $password
Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXXX-Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
start D:\XXXX\XXXX.bat
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Any error message?

Comment: job is successful, but its not hitting the exe, as i cant see any logs for it, where as while hititng the same from my local machine to  server i can see logs generated.

Comment: If you put `Write-Output "Executing remote script"` in your scriptblock before invoking the batch file, do you get `Executing remote script` written to the Jenkins log at least?

Comment: Yes that i already tried, before and after the start script. Its printing the logs but job is not getting started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this by passing the sessionName Parameter in Invoke-command, and using the same sessionname within script so that it will use the same session to run the script as well

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computername-Credential $cred -InDisconnectedSession -SessionName "RemoteSession" -ScriptBlock {
write-host "Start"
Get-PSSession "RemoteSession"
<<Script>>
write-host "End"
}
```